# How can I access a tty from the terminal?

Tags: gnome-terminal, tty, virtual-terminal

How can I access a tty (eg tty1) from the `gnome-terminal`? Can I set up a profile which does that?

I know the switch using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1-6</kbd>

Comment: What do you mean by "access", and "terminal"?  tty1 IS a terminal.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some options:

- `sudo chvt 1` will bring you to the first virtual console. Putting this in a `.profile` should not be very useful.
- Snooping on a running virtual console is allegedly possible with `ttysnoop`.

Comment: Not really what i'm looking for

Comment: Then please give more detail.

Comment: i want to interact with the tty from `gnome-terminal`

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if it is possible from *within* a terminal, but you can change to another tty by pressing Ctrl + Alt + F1-7 which shows a CLI outside your graphical environment.

Pressing Ctrl + Alt + F7 will show your desktop again. Very useful if you are running a server, which does not have a graphical environment by default.

Comment: He specifically states that that's not what he's looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe your needs lead to you to [xterminator.](http://software.jessies.org/terminator/)

It's a powerfull software to deal with terminal minor problems with some elegance.